# Cannot use numpy.savetxt for a matrix of [string, float, float]

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to save a three-column matrix like this one

```
[ ['1/0' '-2.0' '2.3058220360827992e-11'],
 ['1.0/0.02857142857142857' '-2.0' '2.010818928071975e-12'],
 ['1.0/0.05714285714285714' '-2.0' '5.8909978692050895e-12']]
```

using np.savetxt

I ve tried to define the columns with

```
np.savetxt('FFT', RESULT, fmt=' '.join(['%s'] + ['%f']*2))
```

and

```
np.savetxt('FFT', RESULT,fmt='%s %1.4f %1.4f')
```

but it keeps giving me the same error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments, encoding)
   1386                 try:
-> 1387                     v = format % tuple(row) + newline
   1388                 except TypeError:

TypeError: must be real number, not numpy.str_

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-eecf9f5ea0b0> in <module>
     58 RESULT = np.delete(RESULT, (0), axis=0)
     59 print (RESULT)
---> 60 np.savetxt('FFT', RESULT, fmt=' '.join(['%s'] + ['%f']*2))
     61 
     62 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments, encoding)
   1389                     raise TypeError("Mismatch between array dtype ('%s') and "
   1390                                     "format specifier ('%s')"
-> 1391                                     % (str(X.dtype), format))
   1392                 fh.write(v)
   1393 

TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U23') and format specifier ('%s %f %f')
```

I would like to save it as three rows in order to have a 3d graph with a equispaced x axis with that '1/something' as labels, a y axis determined by the valors of the second row and the third one as the colors on a matplotlib, heatmap. This is not important for the problem, anyway.
Sorry for the bad english, and thank you for your help!

Comment: Just look at you three column matrix - I only see strings, no floats. `'3.14'` is a string, `3.14` is a float.

Comment: This `'1/0' '-2.0' '2.3058220360827992e-11'`, as NumPy is telling you, is _a single string_ (of dtype `<U23`), not three numbers or a string and two floats.